# CDI Scope for Scheduler which inject DB Session into Services

Tags: java, cdi

#### The Context

I am working on a web application in which I try to integrate Vaadin and DB4O and CDI running in TomEE container. In order to have database transactions I have created ServletFilter which intercepts all request and commits or rollbacks at the end of the request.

```java
@WebFilter("/*")
public class DBTransactionHandler implements Filter {

    @Inject
    SessionImpl sessionImpl;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
     ServletException {
            boolean hadException = false;
            try {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    hadException = true;
                    throw ex;
            } finally {
                    if (sessionImpl != null) {
                            if (hadException || sessionImpl.isRollbackOnly()) {
                                    sessionImpl.rollback();
                            } else {
                                    sessionImpl.commit();
                            }
                            sessionImpl.close();
                    }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I have a SessionImpl which is made to be `@RequestScoped`. With this I am trying to achieve that all the services which need to use database while processing a HTTP request then them should get the same instance therefore it will be executed int the same database transaction.

```java
/**
* http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/platform_specific_issues/web/servlets.htm
*/
@RequestScoped
public class SessionImpl implements Session {

    @Inject
    DBConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private boolean rollbackOnly;

    private ObjectContainer delegate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
            delegate = connectionFactory.getConnection().ext().openSession();
    }
    //.... many other database related methods
}
```

All of my service is derived from `AbstractService` so they have a working session immediately.

```java
public class AbstractService {

    @Inject
    protected BeanManager beanManager;

    @Inject
    protected Session db;

}
```

That's what I have at the moment and here comes my problem:

#### The Question

In my web application I need to create a *Scheduler* component. The scheduled jobs will use the same services what I already have. Since the `SessionImpl` is `@RequestScoped` and I have no HTTP Request in a scheduled job the SessionImpl cannot be injected.

- Can I activate somehow the RequestScope Context from a scheduler thread?

What I was trying to do is to create a custom scope `@SchedulerScoped`. This would be activated just before the scheduler starts to execute the job. The problem with this approach was that when I added a second scope to the `SessionImpl` then my application does not deploy anymore:

```
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansConfigurationException: Managed Bean implementation class : org.reluxa.db.SessionImplstereotypes must declare the same @Scope annotations.
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.DefinitionUtil.defineScopeType(DefinitionUtil.java:390)
    at org.apache.webbeans.component.creation.AbstractBeanCreator.defineScopeType(AbstractBeanCreator.java:145)
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.WebBeansUtil.defineManagedBean(WebBeansUtil.java:2548)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.BeansDeployer.defineManagedBean(BeansDeployer.java:552)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.deployManagedBeans(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:407)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I would propose the following as an outline of a solution *I have not actually tried*, so it will need some tweaking:

- Make `SessionImpl` non-CDI: Remove `@RequestScoped`, `@Inject`.
- Make a CDI bean with a producer method that creates `Session`s as follows:

  ```
  // I believe it should be @ApplicationScoped
  public class SessionProducer {
      private ThreadLocal<Session> currentSession;
      @Produces Session makeSession() {
          return currentSession.get();
      }
      public ThreadLocal<Session> getCurrentSessionThreadLocal() {
          return currentSession;
      }
  }
  ```

  So the session resides in a `ThreadLocal` and the producer just gets it from there. Who puts it there?
- Modify your filter to put *and remove* the `Session` in the `ThreadLocal`:

  ```
  @WebFilter("/*")
  public class DBTransactionHandler implements Filter {

      @Inject
      DBConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

      @Inject
      SessionProducer sessionProducer;

      ...

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
          boolean hadException = false;
          try {
              SessionImpl sessionImpl = new SessionImpl();
              sessionImpl.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
              sessionProducer.getCurrentSessionThreadLocal().set(sessionImpl);
              // here you probably want to call sessionImpl.init();
              chain.doFilter(request, response);
          } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
              hadException = true;
              throw ex;
          } finally {
              if (sessionImpl != null) {
                  if (hadException || sessionImpl.isRollbackOnly()) {
                      sessionImpl.rollback();
                  } else {
                      sessionImpl.commit();
                  }
                  sessionImpl.close();
                  sessionProducer.getCurrentSessionThreadLocal().set(null);
              }
          }
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

  Up to here, your web configuration should be working as before. Test and tweak as necessary. (Do test that there is only one session produced per thread.)
- Now you will have to repeat the `SessionImpl` creation and destruction ceremony from within the scheduler. This way the services will still see a valid `Session` without the need of the request scope. This "ceremony" could probably be factored out (e.g. a CDI or EJB interceptor for the scheduler that performs these actions, is reusable and does not pollute the business logic of your components with system logic like this).

Comment: Thank you. This pointed out to the solution. With some more tweaks I got a working solution.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you post those points for anyone that may be interested in the future (me included :-), if it is not much for you?

Comment: I did not tell before that my Scheduler component uses CDI to discover Schedulable jobs. This is an interface which extends Runnable adding two methods: getFirstRun(), getPeriod(). When my Scheduler finds a Schedulable it creates an instance of it reads out the time and frequency when it had to be schedule and then it passes this instance to an ExecutorService with the proper parameters.

Comment: Then after when the Executor is running this and the wrapper around this (similar to the DBTransactionHandler above) creates the Session and puts it in the ThreadLocal had no effect on my Schedulable because the object was already constructed, and all the @Injections were done.

Comment: So I created a SessionThreadLocalWrapper (http://pastebin.com/ybqLe2sV). This injected into all of the services and this then delegates all the session related requests to the SessionImpl belonging to the actual thread. You can find the full sourcecode here: https://github.com/reluxa/VDC

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting!